# How to subtract values of two different columns from two different tables?

Tags: php, mysql

Example Table Structure

**Table 1**

```
ID      |    Name    |  Price
-----------------------------
1       |   Casio    |  30
2       |   Titan    |  40
```

**Table 2**

```
ID      |    Place   |  Price
-----------------------------
1       |   Cali    |  30 

2       |   Mexi    |  10
```

Operation to perform:
 **Table1(Price) - Table2(Price) for ID = 1**

**New Table 1**

```
ID      |    Name    |  Price
-----------------------------
1       |   Casio    |  0
2       |   Titan    |  40
```

ID matches in both tables

Comment: Does records from different tables match by ID column? If so, why these records are in different tables?

Comment: first of all I don't see logic of subtracting table1.casio.price-table.cali.price. second are you sure both table will contain same number of rows?

Comment: Yes ID matches in both column

Comment: Im trying to implement shopping website db 
one is your cart with different attributes another is your stocks left

Comment: If so, then these column do not match by ID. In the first table it is a good id, in the second table it is a place id, and there is one to may relation, because it could be that Casio is in Cali and it is in Mexi. And as the result IDs do not match

Answer (score 1):

You should consider another database design to handle this case.

But to answer your question, you can create a view :

```
create view Differences2 as (
    select t1.id, t1.price - t2.price
    from t1, t2
    where t1.id = t2.id
)
```

Comment: This answer calculates a difference between every record from Table1 and every record from Table2, even if records do not match. I guess, there must be "WHERE" condition in your answer.

Comment: Thank you, forgot the where clause :)

Answer (score 1):

As you told both table will have same ID column you can use following query.

```
SELECT table1.ID, table1.Name, (table1.Price-table2.Price) AS Price 
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID
```

If you want to update record you can use following:

```
UPDATE table1
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID
        SET table1.Price = (table1.Price-table2.Price)
```

Comment: This answer assumes "Yes ID matches in both column", but i believe it is a wrong comment, as far as first ID represents good, the second ID represent place. and there should be one to many or many to many relation.

Comment: @yvs I do agree with you that is what I asked in comments and it seems illogical to me too. Because how casio price subtract from cali price