# How to get Product wise stock using MySQL server query

Tags: mysql

I want to get product stock details from 2 different tables i.e. stock_in and stock_out tables. I want to get the total remained stock quantity values grouped by product name.

My stock input table looks like:

```
---------------------------------
id | product name | product qty
________________________________
1      product 1      20
```

My Product out table looks like:

```
_____________________________
id | product name  | product qty
____________________________
1     product 1        4
__________________________
```

And I want output like this:

```
_________________________________
id | product name  | product qty
_________________________________
1      product 1       16
__________________________________
```

Comment: It's really difficult to read and understand your tables

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something specific, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Comment: Code code Code code Code code...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to subtract values of two different columns from two different tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40827363/how-to-subtract-values-of-two-different-columns-from-two-different-tables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this query will solve this problem

```
SELECT a.id, a.product_name, (a.product_quantity - b.product_quantity) as product_quantity
From stock_in as a, stock_out as b
Where a.product_name = b.product_name
```

Comment: thank you for your reply,  when i execute the query it shows error at where clause b.product_name

Comment: try SELECT stock_in.id, stock_in.product_name, (stock_in.product_quantity - stock_out.product_quantity) as product_quantity
From stock_in JOIN stock_out
ON stock_in.product_name = stock_out.product_name